# Where i can find a jar of play service ads?

Tags: java, android, jar, admob

I am unable to find a jar file of play service ads which contains AdView.class,AdListener.class,AdRequest.class , OnInitializationStatus.class.

Actually, I want a admob jar to create Banner , interstitial and rewarded ads

Comment: Why didn't the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) on how to use AdMob work for you?

Comment: Thats my problem i am using other compiler where i have only jar option

Comment: I don't think it's made to be used like that but https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=play-services-ads#com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0, links to an aar which you can unzip and find a classes.jar inside.